# Remove numbering using roman numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove valid roman numbers ( numbering) from a text that contains headlines, Paragraphs, etc...

I'm using this **regex** :

```
Pattern ROMAN = Pattern.compile("^[([]‌?x{0,3}(i[xv]‌|v?i{0,3})[)\.]/]{1,2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Although it matches also empty parenthesis.

What I want to do is to remove the following:

```
Input :
iv. foo foo foo.
Output:
foo foo foo.
```

```
Input :
v) foo foo foo.
Output:
foo foo foo.
```

But also do nothing when not using them for numbering:

```
Input :
foo foo foo i) foo v) .
Output:
foo foo foo i) foo v) .
```

Another example of what the regex should match :
`iv)` `X)`
`ix/` `V/`
`x.` `IV.`

Comment: Do the numbers need to be valid? Else you could just use `/^[IVXLCM]+[).]/i`

Comment: They are pre-valid numbers , so yes , I think the regex should match only valid numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like the following [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/rUcRCI/1):

```
^((?=[mdclxvi])m*(c[md]|d?c{0,3})(x[cl]|l?x{0,3})(i[xv]|v?i{0,3})(?:\)|\.))
```

This matches a roman number that is followed by either `)` or `.` characters. There is a nice article about matching roman numbers [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch06s09.html) by Steven Levithan, Jan Goyvaerts from O'Reilly.

Comment: Just a note: the proposed regex needs to be applied in a case insensitive manner. E.g by adding `(?i)` at the front or by using `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Comment: You're welcome, anyway great answer. And the link you've provided is also very helpful (at least the part that one can read freely) :)

Comment: I find the O'Reilly edition very helpful at all. I recommend those books.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will do it:

```
^\s*(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(CM|D?C{0,3}|CD)(XC|L?X{0,3}|XL)(IX|V?I{0,3}|IV)[.)/]
```

[See explanation...](https://regex101.com/r/eO5jix/3)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Cs*(%3F%3D%5BMDCLXVI%5D)M*(CM%7CD%3FC%7B0%2C3%7D%7CCD)(XC%7CL%3FX%7B0%2C3%7D%7CXL)(IX%7CV%3FI%7B0%2C3%7D%7CIV)%5B.)%2F%5D)

Comment: Thanks @Norbert ,  I was wondering if there was latin ```[a-z][A-Z]``` instead of roman numbers or numbers or and latin letters eg: ```3. a) ``` or ```(a)``` how can do the same ?

Comment: Than your regular expression would be `^\s*[a-zA-Z]+[.)/]`.